# SQL Min value not being selected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement with a joining table, and I am attempting to select the first row of the joined table.

For example, `dbo.Projects` has many `dbo.Buffers`.

My query is:

```
SELECT PM.PROJECTID, PM.PROJECTNAME, BU.PERCENTPENWREALIGNED
FROM dbo.PROJECTMGRVIEW AS PM
JOIN dbo.S2M_BUFFER AS BU ON BU.PROJECTID = ( SELECT DISTINCT MIN(TASKUNIQUEID) FROM dbo.S2M_BUFFER WHERE PROJECTID = PM.PROJECTID )
WHERE PM.PROJECT_TYPE = 8 AND PM.CATEGORY = 'Engineering' ANd PM.PROJECTID = 244;
```

My result set is many rows:

```
PROJECTID | PROJECTNAME | PERCENTPENWREALIGNED
244       | PROJECT A   | 100
244       | PROJECT A   | 0
244       | PROJECT A   | 0
244       | PROJECT A   | 0
244       | PROJECT A   | 0
244       | PROJECT A   | 0
244       | PROJECT A   | 0
```

Obviously in this case, I simply need the first row.

Comment: Is top 1 not working for you. I mean SELECT TOP 1 COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join doesn't really make any sense, you can't do it using a subquery, but my guess is you want something like this:

```
SELECT PM.PROJECTID, PM.PROJECTNAME, BU.PERCENTPENWREALIGNED
FROM dbo.PROJECTMGRVIEW AS PM
CROSS APPLY (
  select top 1 PERCENTPENWREALIGNED
  from dbo.S2M_BUFFER BU 
  where BU.PROJECTID = PM.PROJECTID
  order by TASKUNIQUEID ASC
) BU
WHERE PM.PROJECT_TYPE = 8 AND PM.CATEGORY = 'Engineering' AND PM.PROJECTID = 244;
```

This will join the row with smallest TASKUNIQUEID in S2M_BUFFER with the PROJECTMGRVIEW

Comment: Spot on. Thank you. I've never used cross apply.

Answer (score 0):

I agree your Join statement seems flawed due a circular reference between the PROJECTID and the TASKUNIQUEID.

I think this might be more what you were trying to do:

```
SELECT PM.PROJECTID, PM.PROJECTNAME, BU.PERCENTPENWREALIGNED
FROM dbo.PROJECTMGRVIEW AS PM
JOIN dbo.S2M_BUFFER AS BU ON BU.TASKUNIQUEID = 
( SELECT DISTINCT MIN(TASKUNIQUEID) FROM dbo.S2M_BUFFER WHERE PROJECTID = PM.PROJECTID )
WHERE PM.PROJECT_TYPE = 8 AND PM.CATEGORY = 'Engineering' ANd PM.PROJECTID = 244;
```